# Why does spark shuffling not spill to disk ?

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory, heap-memory, word-count

The simple wordcount program in spark doesn’t spill to disk and results in OOM error. In short:

**The environment:**

```
Spark: 2.3.0, Scala 2.11.8
3 x Executor, each: 1 core + 512 MB RAM
Text file: 341 MB
Other configurations are default (spark.memory.fraction = 0.6)
```

**The code:**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object WordCount {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val inPath = args(0)

        val sc = new SparkContext("spark://master:7077", "Word Count ver3")
        val words = sc.textFile(inPath, minPartitions = 20)
                      .map(line => line.toLowerCase())
                      .flatMap(text => text.split(' '))
        val wc = words.groupBy(word => word)
                      .map({ case (groupName, groupList) => (groupName, groupList.size) })
                      .count()
    }
}
```

**The error:**

```
2018-05-04 13:46:36 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 21, 192.168.10.107, executor 0): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:325)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readAscii(Input.java:598)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readString(Input.java:472)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:195)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:184)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream.readKey(Serializer.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**The heapdump:**

[image: Heap Dump]

**The problems are:**

1. Heapsize for execution would be (512 - 300) * 0.6 = 127 MB (since I don’t use cache). Why does the ExternalAppendOnlyMap size is more than 380 MB ? The class must be stored in heap memory, and its size cannot be larger than the heap size.
2. The ExternalAppendOnlyMap is a spillable class, and it should spill its data to disk due to lack of memory in this case, but in this case it didn’t, results in a OOM error.
3. Heap memory of the program is divided into: Spark execution memory and user memory. Look into the heap dump, which objects will be stored in which division of heap memory ?

Really appreciated for your time.